# How did Charley Varrick know to hide?

Tags: plot-explanation, charley-varrick

In the 1973 Don Siegel movie [Charley Varrick](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069865/), the eponymous protagonist leads a team of bank robbers in a raid on a small regional bank. The job is supposed to be an easy raid but they accidentally find they have netted an implausible amount of cash. Varrick realises they have stumbled on a Mafia drop and that the mob will seek them out to make an example of them if they try to use the money.

Leaving his drunk partner in his trailer, he begins to plan what looks like an escape from the country, seeking passports etc.. He doesn't know at this point that the mob have identified him and sent an enforcer to take action. But, when he returns to his trailer, instead of going inside to talk to his partner, he hides in a ditch in the trailer park observing the enforcer arrive at the trailer to torture his partner.

How does he know to hide when he couldn't know the mob have found him so quickly?